# How return object that has specific value in string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

So I have array with object inside. That object has a property call name that is a string of values

How can I return object that has "apples" in the name properties

```
fruits = [
{
name: 'apples, lemon',
quantity: 2
},
{
name: 'bananas, pearl',
quantity: 0
},
{
name: 'cherries,
pineapple',
quantity: 5
}
];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
var fruits = [
{
name: 'apples, lemon',
quantity: 2
},
{
name: 'bananas, pearl',
quantity: 0
},
{
name: 'cherries, pineapple',
quantity: 5
}
];

const filteredFruits = fruits.filter(item => item.name.includes("apples"));
console.log(filteredFruits);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for !

Comment: If its helpful please mark it as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
let fruits=[{name:'apples, lemon',quantity:2},{name:'bananas, pearl',quantity:0},{name:'cherries, pineapple',quantity:5}];

let filteredFruits = fruits.filter(fruit => {
  return fruit.name.indexOf("apples") !== -1;
});

console.log(filteredFruits);
```